# How do we write a particular C code for a square wave converter? Or what is the logic for that?

Tags: c, fpga

I want to write a **c code** for **square wave converter** for some calculation purposes.But I don't have any idea about c code logic for a square wave . 
Please suggest me any logic which can help me to write a c code for the square wave converter.

Comment: You need to stat learning C. I'd suggest you start coding, and in the obstacles, ask for help. Not the other way around. You can search online for tutorial sites, like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=c+tutorial+online&rlz=1C1GCEU_enPT848PT848&oq=c+tutorial&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l7.4623j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I'd say the same thing like @RuiSilva. You used the FPGA tag. FPGA's are usually "coded" in VHDL or Verilog, which are totally different things from C. C is a procedual programming languages, while VHDL/Verilog are hardware description languages. The "sqare wave converter logic" could easily achieved with both languages, but with different architectual background. Start learning C/VHDL for that matter, and then you'll find the answer yourself pretty quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A square wave is the easiest, after all its either high or low, on or off, true of false.

If you're wanting to output a square wave then just toggle an output on your FPGA (if that is what this is) in relation to a timer.

If you're converting an analogue signal to a square wave then you'll need to test against a value, **that you set**, below which your output is low and above which your output high.

This is the basis of digitizing an analogue signal.